# Comparing dates in GridDataItem cell in order to color that cell

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I need to change color of a cell - which is dependent on a date - i can change color of cell no issue here

```
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;

        **if ((item["run_Date"].Text > DateTime.Now))** //error is in this line of code
        {
            foreach (GridColumn col in radgrdResultDetail.MasterTableView.Columns)
            {
                item["run_Date"].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 106, 106);

            }
        }
```

however its trying to access the "Date" - that i'm coming across my error
i've attached an image of my e.item

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the exact error message you are receiving? My assumption is that you are getting an invalid cast exception as you are comparing a String cell.Text to a DateTime object DateTime.Now. Try converting the text to a datetime object like this:

```
if(DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(item["run_date"].Text), DateTime.Now) > 0)
```

or look at the cell itself, which I think returns an object, and cast it to a datetime object

```
if(DateTime.Compare((DateTime)item["run_date"], DateTime.Now) > 0)
```

Comment: Hi Matt - i'm getting the issue "Cannot find a cell bound to column name 'run_Date'"

Comment: Does the first line using the .Text property work? If not is this a templated field/cell? If it is a templated field/cell you will need to find the actual control that holds the value. for example TextBox tBox = (TextBox)item["run_date"].FindControl("<name of display control in template>");
couple of links that might be helpful:

[Telerik Forum topic](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/316967-griddataitem.aspx)

[Telerik help accessing cells and rows](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-accessing-cells-and-rows.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    //Is it a GridDataItem
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        //Get the instance of the right type
        GridDataItem item= e.Item as GridDataItem;

        //Check the formatting condition
        if(DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(item["run_date"].Text), DateTime.Now) > 0)
        {
            item["run_Date"].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 106, 106);
            //Customize more...
        }
    }
}
```

Ref:
[Conditional formatting for rows/cells on ItemDataBound](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-appearance-conditional-formatting.html)
[How to change row color for RadGrid with specified conditions?](http://humrahimcs.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/how-to-change-row-color-for-radgrid-with-specified-conditions/)